# Django: Changing project folder / settings structure

Tags: django

I am currently trying to change from the default Django structure to that one.

[image]

I now copied all the files in the new folders, but when running `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.local` it shows the following in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
I also changed in my wsgi.py and manage.py to the following:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
```

[image]

Comment: you don't have settings.py in conf/settings

Comment: Ah okay. Do I need settings.py? I just tried to changed it to `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.base")`. Is that what you meant? It doesn't work either.

Comment: Is there a `__init__.py` file in your settings directory?

Comment: no, expand all of your directories and add the new screen shot

Comment: @Eric attached/replaced the new screenshot

Comment: @fxgx yes, that's existing

Comment: @JonProgrammer still don't see it.  Basically, just find which directory has your 'settings.py' file and do os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<the path to the directory that has settings.py>")

Comment: I replaced the settings.py file with `basic.py, local,py` etc.
`basic.py` is the old `settings.py`

Comment: Your settings directory is not under the root directory of the project, it is under `config` directory so can you try `python manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.local`. And remember to remove `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE..."` from your manage.py

Comment: Ah okay, interesting. Just removing it? Not replacing it with anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the `config/` directory into a python module by creating a blank `config/__init__.py` file, then configure your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` like this in `manage.py` and `config/wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
```

Then you should be able to just run `./manage.py runserver` without the `--settings` option.

Comment: Hi @Niicodemus, I now added the __init__, I added `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")` to both files but I still get an `error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lumis'`. These are basically the apps I registered in my settings. I tested the settings in my old setup where it still works.

Comment: Here a picture of my folder structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TSByy6SzzQD2H13cXwSh5WE2csOJLCfr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure without digging through your exact setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell django where to look for settings module therefore you have to specify the module path in `manage.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
```

and in `__init__.py` inside settings folder add the following lines:

```
try:
    from config.settings.local import *
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get this error message here. In @Niccodemus post below, I shared my folder structure.

Error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HT19fAklRw6I8qpbJ9qvBxftoYc-Z83B/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Pycharm go to 
File > Settings > Language and Frameworks >Django
and configure that

```
1)[checked]  Django support 
2) settings: config\settings.py
3)manage script: manage.py
```

[image]

But if you are using a independent console it should be works fine just with the `___init__.py` file in the folder config ,and the configuration `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")` in `the manage.py` file,using

```
python manage.py runserver
```